# Sharepoint link issue

Tags: excel

I am having a weird issue. I uploaded an excel document to sharepoint, and when I click the link it does not do anything, however if I right click open in new tab it opens. ** This is an excel document saved to html** Googling around hasn't really brought anything to fruition, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,

Comment: Is this behavior same for every excel file and every document library on your site?

Comment: No, it seems to just be one document.

Comment: I'd try to save that document in different format (older or newer xls). If it's problem only with this file, it will not be sharepoint issue.

Comment: Which version of Excel do you use? 2003 and earlier or 2007 or greater? This may be a 2003 and earlier issue.